# Multiple conditions on MDX query

Tags: reporting-services, filter, where-clause, mdx

I have the following MDX query:

```
WITH
 member [Measures].[USD Sales YTD] as (
    SUM( {[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201501]:[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201506]},[Measures].[USD Sales] ))
 member [Measures].[USD Sales LY YTD] as (
    SUM ( {[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201401]:[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201406]},[Measures].[USD Sales]))
member [Measures].[Unit Sales YTD] as (
    SUM ( {[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201501]:[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201506]},[Measures].[Unit Sales]))
member [Measures].[Unit Sales LY YTD] as (
    SUM ( {[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201401]:[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201406]},[Measures].[Unit Sales]))

 SELECT 
 NON EMPTY {  [Measures].[USD Sales YTD] 
     , [Measures].[USD Sales LY YTD]
     , [Measures].[Unit Sales YTD]
     , [Measures].[Unit Sales LY YTD]
     } ON COLUMNS
 , NON EMPTY { 
    (
    [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month]
    * [Customer].[Customer Name].[Customer Name]
    * [Part].[Part #].[Part #]
    * [Sales Rep].[Sales Reps].[Sales Rep]
    ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES [Part].[Part #].[Part Desc], MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( [Sales Rep].[Sales Reps].[Sales Rep].&[12]) ON COLUMNS
    FROM ( SELECT (  [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201506]) ON COLUMNS
        FROM [AlphaBI]) 
        )
WHERE ( {[Part].[Sales Unit].&[B], [Part].[Sales Unit].&[M]})
```

It works fine.  It's giving me the month, customer, product, salesman and Sales YTD, Sales LYTD, Units YTD and Units LYDT.

Recently, a user asked me to change the WHERE condition to say if it's Sales than use sales unit **B** & **M** (like now), BUT if it's Units, then just **B**.  Do you know how I can do that?  In SQL it would be pretty easy, but my MDX skills are a bit rusty.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: By looking at the question, it initially felt as if there is parameter to decide what to choose. Now that you have explicitly mentioned there is no such parameter, please clarify how you decide if it's "Sales" or "Units"?

Comment: I apologize if I didn't make that clear.  There are 2 measures, USD Sales (money) and Units sold (int).  The user wants to see both on the report, but for Units he only wants to see where the Sales Unit condition is B, and for Sales he wants to see where Sales Unit is both B and M.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a small condition in your `WHERE` clause, just like in SQL using `IIF`

```
WHERE (
        {
          [Part].[Sales Unit].&[B],
          IIF(@param = "sales", [Part].[Sales Unit].&[M], null)
        }
      )
```

This will select the members `[Part].[Sales Unit].&[B]` and `[Part].[Sales Unit].&[M]` if the parameter selected is "sales", otherwise selects only `[Part].[Sales Unit].&[B]`

If you want to go a step even further and add even one more level of check, like if "none" is selected, it should add Sales Unit "A", then use nested `IIF` statements like so -

```
IIF(@param = "sales", [Part].[Sales Unit].&[M], IIF(@param = "units", null, [Part].[Sales Unit].&[A])
```

Assuming no additional checks are required, the code should look like -

```
 WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[USD Sales YTD] AS
  SUM(
        {
         [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201501]
         :
         [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201506]
        },
        [Measures].[USD Sales]
     )

  MEMBER [Measures].[USD Sales LY YTD] AS
  SUM (
         {
          [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201401]
          :
          [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201406]
         },
         [Measures].[USD Sales]
      )

  MEMBER [Measures].[Unit Sales YTD] AS
  SUM (
         {
          [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201501]
          :
          [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201506]
         },
         [Measures].[Unit Sales]
      )

  MEMBER [Measures].[Unit Sales LY YTD] AS
  SUM (
         {
          [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201401]
          :
          [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201406]
         },
         [Measures].[Unit Sales]
     )

SELECT
  NON EMPTY 
  {
    [Measures].[USD Sales YTD],
    [Measures].[USD Sales LY YTD],
    [Measures].[Unit Sales YTD],
    [Measures].[Unit Sales LY YTD]
  } ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY 
  {
    (
      [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month] *
      [Customer].[Customer Name].[Customer Name] *
      [Part].[Part #].[Part #] * 
      [Sales Rep].[Sales Reps].[Sales Rep]
    )
  } DIMENSION PROPERTIES [Part].[Part #].[Part Desc], member_caption,
  member_unique_name ON ROWS
FROM ( SELECT
       (
         [Sales Rep].[Sales Reps].[Sales Rep].&[12]
       ) ON COLUMNS
     FROM ( SELECT
            (
              [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201506]
            ) ON COLUMNS
          FROM [AlphaBI]) )
WHERE (
        {
          [Part].[Sales Unit].&[B],
          IIF(@param = "sales", [Part].[Sales Unit].&[M], null)
        }
      )
```

**EDIT 2**

Does this help? I have moved the association with `Sales Unit` attribute to the definition of member instead of `WHERE` clause.

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[USD Sales YTD] AS
  SUM(
        {
         [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201501]
         :
         [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201506]
        }
        *
        {
          [Part].[Sales Unit].&[B],
          [Part].[Sales Unit].&[M]
        }
        ,
        [Measures].[USD Sales]
     )

  MEMBER [Measures].[USD Sales LY YTD] AS
  SUM (
         {
          [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201401]
          :
          [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201406]
         }
        *
        {
          [Part].[Sales Unit].&[B],
          [Part].[Sales Unit].&[M]
        }
        ,
         [Measures].[USD Sales]
      )

  MEMBER [Measures].[Unit Sales YTD] AS
  SUM (
         {
          [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201501]
          :
          [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201506]
         }
        *
        {
          [Part].[Sales Unit].&[B]
        }
        ,
         [Measures].[Unit Sales]
      )

  MEMBER [Measures].[Unit Sales LY YTD] AS
  SUM (
         {
          [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201401]
          :
          [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201406]
         }
        *
        {
          [Part].[Sales Unit].&[B]
        }
        ,
         [Measures].[Unit Sales]
     )

SELECT
  NON EMPTY 
  {
    [Measures].[USD Sales YTD],
    [Measures].[USD Sales LY YTD],
    [Measures].[Unit Sales YTD],
    [Measures].[Unit Sales LY YTD]
  } ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY 
  {
    (
      [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month] *
      [Customer].[Customer Name].[Customer Name] *
      [Part].[Part #].[Part #] * 
      [Sales Rep].[Sales Reps].[Sales Rep]
    )
  } DIMENSION PROPERTIES [Part].[Part #].[Part Desc], member_caption,
  member_unique_name ON ROWS
FROM ( select {[Part].[Sales Unit].&[B], [Part].[Sales Unit].&[M]} FROM (
SELECT
       (
         [Sales Rep].[Sales Reps].[Sales Rep].&[12]
       ) ON COLUMNS
     FROM ( SELECT
            (
              [Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201506]
            ) ON COLUMNS
          FROM [AlphaBI]) ) )
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but this is a scheduled report that contains the 4 columns (Sales, Sales LY, Units, Units LY).  There are no parameter, I'm trying to return all 4 columns in one grid.

Comment: @AlexFreitas - Check now.

Comment: Yes! I think that's what I need.  The only problem is that now the query is taking forever to run, so I'm trying to figure out why it'd do that.

Comment: @AlexFreitas - Edited code. Try Edit2. I added one more subselect, which should effectively speed up the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't feed our `mdx` into `RS` so guessing a bit)

Can you add in a parameter into your report (I've called it `@switch`) which dynamically creates a set at the top of your script- this is then referenced in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WITH
 set [whereSet] AS
     strToSet(
       iif(@switch = "Both",
          "{[Part].[Sales Unit].&[B], [Part].[Sales Unit].&[M]}"
         ,"{[Part].[Sales Unit].&[B]}" 
       )
     )
 member [Measures].[USD Sales YTD] as (
    SUM( {[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201501]:[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201506]},[Measures].[USD Sales] ))
 member [Measures].[USD Sales LY YTD] as (
    SUM ( {[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201401]:[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201406]},[Measures].[USD Sales]))
member [Measures].[Unit Sales YTD] as (
    SUM ( {[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201501]:[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201506]},[Measures].[Unit Sales]))
member [Measures].[Unit Sales LY YTD] as (
    SUM ( {[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201401]:[Invoice Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201406]},[Measures].[Unit Sales]))

SELECT 
...
...
WHERE [whereSet]
```

Comment: whytheq - Sorry to digress - You didn't respond to my comment on this question on RS tag - http://stackoverflow.com/q/31452382/2993606